# How to check if a probability from a logistic regression model is significantly above chance level?

Tags: probability, logistic

I've made a binary logistic regression model with three different variables
X1 (three levels)
X2 (five levels)
X3 (two levels)
to compare the chances of being sick or not (YES/NO).

From the logistic regression model, I have the odds ratios but also the probabilities for each level of each variable. Now, we know that the the odds ratios tell us that some level of a variable has less or more chances than the reference category to get sick. For example, X1a has 2.589 more chances than X1c to get sick, with a significant p value. Knowing the probabilities of X1a (e.g., 45.18%) and the reference X1c (e.g., 24.15%), we can say that there is a difference of 21.03 percentage points between the two. However, what we don't know, it is the probability of X1a above chance... The reference (intercept) being significant, we could say that X1c is below chance of being sick. But what about X1a ? Is there a way to say that not only it differs significantly from the reference, but also from chance ? having a probability of 45.18% to get sick can be greater than a probability of 24.15%, but is it statistically different from chance (50%) ? That's what I would be able to say... Would it be ok to take each of these probability to run a binomial test and compare it to chance (0.5) ?

I don't know if what I say make sense, I'm sorry for the confusion...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to test. 
Do you want to test if variable $x_1 = a$ signficantly increases the risk of a disease ? 
If yes, you would need to tell compare to what ($x_1 =b$, $x_1 = c$...).

Comment: @Pohoua Thanks for you comment. I'll try to reformulate. I do not only want a comparison between X1=a to X1=c, I also want to compare X1=a to a distribution of 50% with disease and 50% without.